# Подргузка картинок xcode

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день уважаемые гуру. Столкнулся с проблемой с загрузкой картинок.
У меня кастомная таблица и каждый слот подгружает картинку. Вполне естественно, что при таких то действиях и 100 картинок все лагает. Как мне оптимизировать этот процесс?

Загрузка идет таким способом.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:images]];
cell.companyImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

P.S. В кастом ячейки просто картинка, потом добавяться еще елементы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Картинки грузить надо асинхронно, проще всего, наверное, через NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: queue:completionHandler:, но он только с 5.0 появился

Comment: Спасибо, работает!